# android return wrong ArrayList values

Tags: android, arraylist, return-value

I'm trying to pass a `List<String[]>` between functions but I got a weird result.

The function!

```
public List<String[]> tes(){

    List<String[]> test = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    String[] temp = {"a","b","c"};
    test.add(temp);

    temp[0] = "d";
    temp[1] = "e";
    temp[2] = "f";

    test.add(temp);

    return test;
 }
```

The extraction.

```
    String output = "";
    List<String[]> Results = db.tes();
    for (String[] row: Results) {
        output = output + row[0] + " " + row[1] + "\n";
    }
```

Result:

```
d e
d e
```

I really don't get it. It should be `a b d e`, but it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one object temp. It means that all object in list have link on your alone temp. Try use `new` for each string and your result will be different.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is because of ,you have added the same object (temp) twice into the list test.

list(test) holding the reference of same object twice.

in case you try change value of object even after adding to list, it will get change in list also, because list holding the reference of object.

Comment: Thank you, that's was the answer I was looking for. It crossed my mind, but I wasn't sure. Thanks!